# Wire Library Timer Usage

Tags: timers, wire-library

I would like to know if the Wire Library is using a Hardware Timer from the Arduino Mega 2560. And If so which Timer it is.

As I am using the Timer 1. After implementing the Wire Library I have some strange things happening that are probably due to the Timer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.

It has its own timer called the "Bit Rate Generator Unit" which is controlled using the `TWBR` register.  It takes its time source direct from the main CPU clock and divides it down.